# c# how can i call click event of image button in html generic control?

Tags: c#, asp.net, htmlgenericcontrol

I tried to call click event but it does not call it 
I tried this codes:  like

```
objImage.Click += new ImageClickEventHandler(WebForm4.ImageButtons_Click);
objImage.Click += WebForm4.ImageButtons_Click;
```

my codes :

```
public HtmlGenericControl CreateDIV_OyVerme_Sub_Yildiz(string id, int subId)
{
    HtmlGenericControl objDiv = new HtmlGenericControl("div");
    objDiv.ID = strControlName_DivYildiz + id + "_" + subId;

    objDiv.Attributes.Add("class", strClassName_DivYildiz);
    //objDiv.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");

    ImageButton objImage = new ImageButton();
    objImage.Attributes.Add("runat", "server");
    objImage.CommandArgument = id; 
    //objImage.Src = strImgSrc_yildiz;
  objImage.Click += new ImageClickEventHandler(WebForm4.ImageButtons_Click);
   //objImage.Click += WebForm4.ImageButtons_Click; 
    objImage.Attributes.Add("onclick", "WebForm4.ImageButtons_Click();");

    objImage.ID = strControlName_ImageYildiz + id +"_" + subId;
    objImage.ImageUrl = strImgSrc_yildiz;
   objImage.OnClientClick = strOnClientClickFunc_yildiz;
   // objImage.Attributes.Add("OnClick","WebForm4.amethod (o;"); 
    objImage.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Height, "19px");
    objImage.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Width, "20px");
    objImage.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BorderWidth, "0px");
    objImage.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Position, "relative");
    objImage.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Top, "13px");
    objImage.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Left, "6px");
    objImage.Style.Add("float", "left");
    objImage.ToolTip = subId + "/" + 5;
    // calling the method 
   // objImage.Attributes.Add("OnClientClick", "return(GetRssID(objRssItem));");

  //  var duck = objRssItem;

  //  objImage.Click += (s, e) => { WebForm4.amethod(objRssItem); };
   //objImage.Click += WebForm4.amethod (objRssItem); 

    objDiv.Controls.Add(objImage);

    return objDiv;
}
```

Comment: Either replace `objImage.Attributes.Add("onclick", "WebForm4.ImageButtons_Click();");` with `objImage.Attributes.Add("onclick", strOnClientClickFunc_yildiz);` or remove `objImage.Attributes.Add("onclick", "WebForm4.ImageButtons_Click();");`, `onclick` and `OnClientClick` run at client-side while `Click` runs at server-side.

Comment: First you register server-side event-handler for server-side click then you register server-side event-handler for client-side click, afterwards you register client-side event-handler for client-side click, clean-up your code.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add the attribute: `onclick`.
remove this line:
 `objImage.Attributes.Add("onclick", "WebForm4.ImageButtons_Click();");`
you can simply do it like this:

```
    ImageButton img = new ImageButton();
        img.Click+=new ImageClickEventHandler(img_Click);
        img.ID = "img";
        img.Attributes.Add("runat","server");

        form1.Controls.Add(img);
```

Comment: public static void ImageButtons_Click(Object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {
             ImageButton objImage = (ImageButton) sender; 
    var myId = objImage.Attributes["MyId"]; 
    var mySubId = objImage.Attributes["MySubId"]; 



        }

Comment: can you tell me exactly what happen? did you see the image on the page browser? and when you click on it it doesn't come to the function? did you try to use brakepoint in the function?

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue in registering the event handler - either of below lines would register the event handler:

```
objImage.Click += new ImageClickEventHandler(WebForm4.ImageButtons_Click);
objImage.Click += WebForm4.ImageButtons_Click;
```

It's a dynamically generated image button, so for event handler to work, you need to ensure that

1. The image button must be re-created and added to control hierarchy on the subsequent post-back. If control is not present on post-back then it cannot raise the event.
2. You must ensure that the control has same ID on the post-back. Not only that it must be in the same control hierarchy and its parents also need to have same ids. The essential point is that control gets located using its ID.
3. The control (image button) must get added to the page's control hierarchy as early as possible - `Page_Init` would be the best but if that's not possible then page_load may work. Creating the control in any subsequent event would not trigger the post-back event.